# WKWebView gives SecurityError when bundling html and javascript with app

Tags: ios, dom, uiwebview, web-sql, wkwebview

We are trying to migrate a hybrid app from UIWebView (iOS < 8) to WKWebView (iOS 8), but we are getting SecurityErrors when trying to store stuff using the [DOM WebDatabase API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) (i.e. 'web sql databases').

The following throws an error if the index.html has been loaded from a bundled file with the app

```
// throws SecurityError: DOM Exception 18
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'key value store', 1);
```

The same code works fine with UIWebView. I can fallback to using Local Storage for some reason, but using WebSQL databases is a no go. I can only speculate that this has something to do with the same origin policy or something related.

The funny thing is that loading index.html from the network works fine :-/

Any clues as to how I can work around this? Any options to set on the WKWebView that fixes it?

This is how we load the web related stuff:

```
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL];

WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
[config.userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self.myCallbacks name:@"NativeApp"];

self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:config];

[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

The html file simply loads a javascript file that has a relative path, "myCode.js".

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue ([OpenRadar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5839348817723392)) with WKWebView in iOS 8.0 (and 8.1 B1, I think) that prevents it from loading local files.  It might be affecting local storage too.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882834/wkwebview-not-working-in-ios-8-beta-4) for more details.

Comment: The question you linked to had some good content in the answers. They give both a workaround and lots of other stuff. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26054170/200987

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding the following method to the UIDelegate of your WKWebView.

```
- (void)                        _webView:(WKWebView *)webView
    decideDatabaseQuotaForSecurityOrigin:(WKSecurityOrigin *)securityOrigin
                            currentQuota:(unsigned long long)currentQuota
                      currentOriginUsage:(unsigned long long)currentOriginUsage
                    currentDatabaseUsage:(unsigned long long)currentUsage
                           expectedUsage:(unsigned long long)expectedUsage
                         decisionHandler:(void (^)(unsigned long long newQuota))decisionHandler {
    decisionHandler(1024*1024*50); //default to 50MB
}
```

It gives all databases a quota of 50MB, instead of the default of 0 which allows them to be opened. This behavior isn't documented, so I don't know where Apple stands with this.

Also, it appears this issue will be fixed in iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a 'plugin' that allows you to use WebSQL (more an implementation of it) in the WKWebView. It can be found here

https://github.com/ajwhiteway/WKWebSQL

```
import WKWebSQL
.
.
.
var webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
WKWebSQL.LoadPlugin(webView)
```

To get it loaded into the page. Versioning isn't really supported at this time. Feel free to add it.