# loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL: in WKWebView

Tags: uiwebview, wkwebview

I'd like to use [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html) instead of a UIWebView to display data on iOS. However, it seems that [loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:) was removed in WKWebView.

Is there any way to mimic this functionality in WKWEbView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could convert your [NSData to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467856/1580288) and use `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` ([API Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/loadHTMLString:baseURL:)).

However, that method has issues with file-system base URLs in the latest beta: [WKWebView not working in iOS 8 beta 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24894281/1580288).

Comment: `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` is just for HTML whereas the original method wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 9.0 and onwards `WKWebView` now has the same method:

`- loadData:MIMEType:characterEncodingName:baseURL:`

That said, I'm currently having issues with certain file types (MS Word) that worked in UIWebView but not in WKWebView.

Comment: Did you ever found out how to display e.g. a Word file in the WKWebView via the `loadData:MIMEType:characterEncodingName:baseURL:` method?

Comment: Hi Pieter, I ended up downloading the file I wanted to open to a temporary directory on the device, and then using the `loadFileURL` method instead of `loadData`. Seems to work well even though it's a bit of a roundabout way of doing it.

Comment: Indeed, that method works (just verified it). Thank you for the response!