# WKWebView not loading local doc file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, wkwebview

I've been trying to load local file contents into `WKWebView` as we're migrating off of `UIWebView`. I noticed that on `UIWebView` I can just pass the file data and it would load perfectly. However, on `WKWebView` I would need to save the file locally to a temp directly then pass that file URL for `WKWebView` to render as discussed by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799977/loaddatamimetypetextencodingnamebaseurl-in-wkwebview?rq=1) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882834/wkwebview-not-loading-local-files-under-ios-8)

My issue is that everything works for for docx/pptx/xlsx files, but for doc/ppt/xls file I would get this error: "The operation couldn't be completed. (OfficeImportErrorDomain error 912) (null)"

This is how I invoke `WKWebView`'s method:

```
webView loadFileURL:self.fileURL allowingReadAccessToURL:self.fileURL
```

Anyone run into similar issue before? If so how did you resolve it?

Comment: I have the same issue with .docx file, however it works as expected with .doc files