# WKWebView and UIMenuController

Tags: ios, ios8, uimenucontroller, wkwebview

I have an app with a `WKWebView` in it.  In this app, I customize the options presented in the `UIMenuController`.  The web view seems to add Copy and Define options to the menu no matter what I do.  If I set myself as first responder and return NO for everything, I still get copy and define options.  And I've implemented my own copy option that does special things depending on user preferences and what exactly is selected. Is there a way to remove these extra options?

**Update**: I've filed this as radar 18487289.

Comment: I've same issue, any progress?

Comment: @avdyushin no. But I am at WWDC. Going to ask someone this week.

Comment: @avdyushin it's a known issue but no timeline. The full fix for now is to hide the menu on willShow and make and present your own with whatever options you want.

Comment: Thanks, will use `UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification` notification...

Comment: hi guys, any updates on this? I try to call menuVisible=NO UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification but it is not hiding the default copy/define/share... menu

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "make and present your own" portion of your current work around?  Do you mean create your own menu from scratch? Somehow manage UIMenuController independently?  Or using something like QBPopupMenu (https://github.com/questbeat/QBPopupMenu)?  Cc: @avdyushin

Comment: I'm using QBPopupMenu. On `WillShow` i've created dummy view outside of screen, and set target rect for UIMenuController in this view. (It will hides system menu). Then show QBPopupMenu on `DidShow` where I want.

Comment: Check my answer in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42510788/4990431) you can get frame of UIMenuController and implement your view after original UIMenuController fades away.

Comment: @davew the issue appears to be resolved in iOS 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in iOS 13 beta 1.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 11, simply subclass `WKWebView` and override `canPerformAction` to return `false`:

```
class WebView : WKWebView {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

For iOS 10 or earlier, swizzle `WKContentView`'s `canPerformAction` method:

```
@objc private extension UIResponder {
    func swizzle_canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}

guard let viewClass = NSClassFromString("WKContentView") as? UIView.Type else { return }
method_exchangeImplementations(
    class_getInstanceMethod(viewClass, #selector(UIResponder.canPerformAction))!,
    class_getInstanceMethod(UIResponder.self, #selector(UIResponder.swizzle_canPerformAction))!
)
```

After remove those web view's build-in menu items, you can add your custom menu items via `UIMenuController.shared` like normal.