# How to check WKWebView has HTML string loaded

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, swift, wkwebview

Currently, WKWebView does NOT support loading local file with URLRequest. Details can be read at: [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882834/wkwebview-not-working-in-ios-8-beta-4)

I tried to create a workaround by reading my local html file and use `webView.loadHTMLString` to manually tell web view to render.

How to I know if `webView` has loaded with HTML, as if I check `webView.URL` to see if it has loaded with an URL.

I truly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set your `WKWebView` `navigationDelegate` property and then define the delegate method `webView:didFinishNavigation:`

```
optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
  didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)
```

which [will be called when the main frame load completes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKNavigationDelegate/webView:didFinishNavigation:).

E.g.,

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView!, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
  println("Finished loading frame")
}
```

Comment: This is what I was forgetting. I was overthinking. Thank you!