# UIWebView cannot read correctly some local HTML5 stuff

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, wkwebview, articulate

Here I come with a new challenge for you all, Objective-C developers:

I'm trying to load some HTML5 exports from [Articulate](https://es.articulate.com/) into an UIWebView. Well, at first sight it's quite simple: just put the HTML5 resources into the project and call index.html.

Well, that simply doesn't work if the HTML5 resource have a complex javascript structure. Specially with `<audio>` and `<video>` tags.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean UIWebView (as mentioned in the question/title) or WKWebView (as mentioned in your answer)?

Comment: There are some other work-arounds for WKWebView here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24882834/1580288

Comment: Hi there @EthanB, it0s just a workaround I fought a couple of days ago at work. It seems that Articulate HTML5 exports don't want to play with UIWebView or WKWebView locally anymore so, in my own answer, I've found a solution. Just sharing with everyone, if it could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been investigating for hours and the solution appeared with some lateral thinking:

If the main problem is that reading  locally doesn't work, but the app requirements forces you to maintain the content offline, then let's serve the content locally!.

Here are the steps I followed to resolve this issue:

1. Embed a web server into your app (I prefer [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer))
2. Let GDCWebServer serve your storyline locally with: `[webServer startWithOptions:@{@"BindToLocalhost": @YES} error:nil];`
3. Use `WKWebView` to call your local web server with: `[wkView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webServer.serverURL]];`

Then you will see your Articulate storyline working perfectly in your app inside a window, with iOS8.

Hope this can help someone.