# wkWebView fails to play local audio

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, ios9, wkwebview

Since the release of iOS9, we can render local HTML with a `wkWebView` using `loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:`

This looks good so far, but we are having problems playing a local mp3 from within the HTML. 
There is an `<audio>` tag with a `src` attribute with a relative path to the mp3 file.

The iOS9-Simulator plays our mp3 correctly, but physical devices don't. Catching the error with JavaScript shows a `networkState NETWORK_NO_SOURCE`, which does not make sense to us...
Using an http URL as `src` and streaming the mp3 from the web works fine.

Has anybody managed to play local audio files with a `wkWebView`?

Comment: same problem, has anyone figured this out?

Comment: Related (I think): https://github.com/RLovelett/WKWebViewVideo a sample project that illustrates the same concept but with a `<video>` tag.

Comment: This seems to have been finally fixed in iOS10.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this issue on iOS 9.2. A video with a local URL would play fine on the simulator but not on device. Debugging using Safari tools showed the video error to the the same No source error.  We filed a radar for it: http://www.openradar.me/24281444 
Here is the crazy part - one kludgy workaround that worked (without having to run a local web host) was that we found if you played a video first in a UIWebView then the wkwebview videos would work.  We took this a step further and used a UIWebview that was hidden to play a half second video with no sound that had an autoplay attribute in the tag and the web view had
`uiWebView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false`
While hacky as anything I have seen it causes the WKWebview to then play videos fine.  So one more solution until they fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that code inside a `WKWebView` cannot access local files. I am not aware if this is intended behaviour or a bug (radar, anyone?)

Before `loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:` was introduced in iOS 9, there was a  [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28676439) to load a local HTML file by copying it to `tmp/www`.

Surprisingly, files there can then be access from inside the `WKWebView` – including media files.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy fix actually you just need to prefix the src URL with localhost and your WKWebview port (default 12344).

**Turn A into B:**

```
<!-- A -->
<audio src="img/beep.mp3" controls></audio>

<!-- B -->
<audio src="http://localhost:12344/img/beep.mp3" controls></audio>
```