# Why does WKWebView.loadFileURL not lead to video playing on devices?

Tags: ios, mp4, wkwebview

The devices are all >= 9.1

This works in the Simulator, for videos and PDFs. On iOS devices, the PDFs load, but the videos (.mp4) do not. I get the circle + triangle that inspires confidence that a video can be played, but no video thumbnail is seen behind it, and tapping that circle-inscribed triangle does nothing!

```
webView.loadFileURL(uRL, allowingReadAccessToURL: uRL)
```

Comment: I noticed this change also. If you tap the triangle it should play. I've not yet researched whether this change can be fixed

Comment: Facing same issue. Interesting though, when I do this from the temp/www directory (which exists for IOS8 workaround) - loadFileURL does work!

Comment: I have the same issue. We have had some success getting it to play if a UIWebview plays it first - but not always able to be replicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780038/wkwebview-fails-to-play-local-audio/34968315#34968315

Comment: This is no longer an issue in iOS 10. Works as expected. Not in iOS 9 though. Video does not play.

Comment: @rams Thanks! What should be done with this question, then?

Comment: @Jessy The question is still valid for iOS 9 and I am looking for an answer too. One option I am toying with is, switch to WebView for iOS 9 or lower and use WKWebView for iOS 10.

Comment: Fought the same problem today. Thank to @rams I came up with the following solution: On iOS 8 and 9 I copy the content to Temp subfolder (doesn't have to be `temp/www`) and play from there. On iOS 10 I play directly from where it is. In my case that's Cache folder.