# iOS9 wkmapview google map listener not response

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, wkwebview

in iOS 9, i use a `wkwebview` to render a google map, i want to listen to google map zoom level using the following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(gMap, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                                            var zoomLevel = gMap.getZoom();
                                            level = zoomLevel;
                                            alert(level);
                                            });
```

i do implement `WKWEBVIEW` delegate and set it to the web view . the alert never shows.

Comment: by the way this is working in uiwebview ,but uiwebview has memory problems ,so after iOS8, i use wkwebview

Answer (score 0):

finally ,i solved the problem ,   in the local html ,i write:`

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="map.js"></script>`
```

when add the code in the question to map.js when init ,it doesn't work.

i manage to get it work by add the following code in object c:

```
    NSString *tripscriptstr = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"tripscript" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *source =  [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:tripscriptstr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

WKUserScript *script = [[WKUserScript alloc]initWithSource:source injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];

[configuration.userContentController addUserScript:script];
```

int the txt file ,is the code in the question

Comment: in ios9 url filewithurl not working, so i solved it by create temp directory like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882834/wkwebview-not-loading-local-files-under-ios-8    i did not update js file after change it in temporary directory