# react native webview load from device local file system

Tags: webview, react-native

I'm trying to load `.html`, `.js`, `.css` files from device's local file system into React Native WebView component. I was able to get the path to the `index.html` file but specifying this as the **url** for the WebView simply throws an error. How would I go about this? Please help!

Answer (score 16):

In react native it is now possible to require an HTML file and use it as the source for the web view like this (the path is relative to the react-native file you use it in):

```js
const webapp = require('./webapp/index.html');
```

and the use it in the **WebView** like this:

```
<WebView source={webapp} />
```

Unfortunately this does not load CSS and JavaScript files, that are referenced in the HTML. A solution could be, to write all the CSS and JS inline (e.g. by using a build process).

Comment: The above snippet works great on iOS. But on Android, it doesn't work on release build but works during development. Any idea why so?

Comment: Actually I don't have an idea. I would expect it to be working on Android as well.

Comment: @varunvs did you find out why its not working on android in release mode?

Comment: There's a bug logged on Github for this issue but closed - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/505 A workaround is to put HTML files in Android assets directory. You can then import it by using source prop of webview. eg: `source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/index.html' }}`

You can check the comments in the Github thread to get more details.

Comment: @varunvs That solution on github is not working either, on Android.

Comment: that might help: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/505#issuecomment-244463151

Comment: in case you decide to use inline js css, this will make your life easy: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-inline

Answer (score 9):

I was able to include html5/javascript into project by using { html: , baseUrl: } as source.
But to be frank, it's more like a lucky shot.

```js
<WebView source={{ html: HTML, baseUrl: 'web/' }} />
```

I have index.html, which require pano2vr_player.js and pano.xml to make this code work.

```js
const HTML = `
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <style type="text/css" title="Default">
   body, div, h1, h2, h3, span, p {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
   }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="pano2vr_player.js">
  </script>
  <div id="container" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  <br>Loading...<br><br>
  This content requires HTML5 with CSS3 3D Transforms or WebGL.
    </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   // create the panorama player with the container
   pano=new pano2vrPlayer("container");
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
     pano.readConfigUrlAsync("pano.xml");
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>`;

class PanoView extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <WebView
          style={{ flex: 1, width: 1024, height: 768 }}
          source={{ html: HTML, baseUrl: 'web/' }}
          javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And finally add files/folder ('/web' same as baseUrl) to XCode project

[image]

And it works! But I'm not sure how...

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled upon the same issue and, after running in circles for hours trying all sorts of solutions, I finally solved it by following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@caphun/react-native-load-local-static-site-inside-webview-2b93eb1c4225). Major kudos to the author.

In the article there's some extra info which is a bit outdated, so here's the concise version instead:

- create a folder in your main project root (e.g. `/html`);
- put all of your files in a folder (e.g. `Web`, with `index.html` being your WebView entrypoint), give it a `.bundle` extension (e.g. `Web.bundle`), and place it into `/html`;

Now you have to add these files to the project so they are recognized and bundled together in your next build, this process is done differently in iOS and Android:

- iOS: open your project in Xcode, drag n drop `Web.bundle` into the project's main folder, and confirm the dialog with the "Copy items if needed" option left unchecked;
- Android: open `/android/app/build.gradle` and add:

```
android {
  ...
  sourceSets { 
    main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', '../../html'] } 
  }
}
```

Now rebuild your project from scratch to have your changes take effect.

In your WebView file, calculate the path to `index.html` and feed it to the WebView:

```js
const sourceUri = (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file:///android_asset/' : '')
    + 'Web.bundle/index.html';

return (
  <WebView
    source={{ uri: sourceUri }}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    allowFileAccess={true}
  />
);
```

This will load your `index.html` and all of its js and css files, as long as they're included in the bundle.

Answer (score 3):

You may have to wrap your own Native Module to do this. React Native's WebView uses `UIWebView`, for info on loading a local file take a look here: https://gist.github.com/amster/9160860

However it is recommended you use `WKWebView`, you can wrap one yourself relatively easily. There is currently a repo that is WIP: https://github.com/qrush/react-native-wkwebview

Accomplishing loading local resources using `WKWebView` can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28676439/398136

Answer (score 0):

Place this script in any file of ReactNative or your code, recomended to first or top index file.
And it will fix problem, tested on RN0.39

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { setCustomSourceTransformer } from 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource';

setCustomSourceTransformer(function (resolver) {

  if (Platform.OS === 'android'
    && !resolver.serverUrl
    && !resolver.bundlePath
    && resolver.asset.type === 'html') {
    resolver.bundlePath = '/android_asset/';
  }

  return resolver.defaultAsset();
});
```