# Include local web app into react native webview

Tags: javascript, css, webview, react-native, single-page-application

Within my react-native app I want to show a webview, that loads a local html5 web application (single page app, SPA).

I am able to load an html file, that is located within the relative folder `webapp` using

```
var webapp = require('./webapp/index.html');
```

and

```
<WebView source={webapp}></WebView>
```

as I have stated in this thread: [react native webview load from device local file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506908/react-native-webview-load-from-device-local-file-system)

Unfortunately, the assets of this local webapp like the .js and .css files, aren't loaded by the webapp.

During development of the react-native app, these files are available via the  development server. Though, when the app is packed and run on an iOS device, the assets aren't available (I get a 404 error in Safari developer tools).

How can I make sure, that all of the assets (JS, CSS, etc.) within the `webapp` folder are available in the packaged app local.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

> By setting the baseURL, the WebView knows where to look for the css/js that you link to

like:

```
<WebView baseURL="/webApp" html={html} />
```

check the answer for the issue on github :

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1442#issuecomment-106906969

or read the example on this detailed answer by nick-weaver:
[Loading javascript into a UIWebView from resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733883/loading-javascript-into-a-uiwebview-from-resources/5810930#5810930)