# How to setup a React Native Webview Proxy?

Tags: webview, react-native, http-proxy

In react native Webview I can give it HTML to render offline but I also want it to load the css and js files offline as well as handle any http traffic while offline.

I have a couple ideas so far: using something like https://github.com/remy/inliner to make the entire site dependency free, or setting up a proxy that sees an http request has been made from inside the Webview and then handles it with react native code.

What would be an easy way to set up a proxy for Webview? I found https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewProxy and going to be looking into it, but would really like to find something cross platform and already bridged with react native.

Comment: Don't know how far you got but this could be an alternative take at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506908/react-native-webview-load-from-device-local-file-system

Comment: @john  did you get any solution with react native