# Load JS/CSS from bundle package with React Native for Android

Tags: android, react-native

I've seen many solutions for loading JS/CSS from a bundle package with a React Native app targeted towards **iOS** like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506908/react-native-webview-load-from-device-local-file-system), but not for **Android**.

My webview code is like this:

```
<WebView
  source={{html: html, baseUrl: `file:///android_asset/web`}}
/>
```

The `html` variable is like this:

```
const html = `
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="someText">Foo</p>
  </body>
</html>`
```

My project directories look like this:

```
app
  -> assets
  -> web
    -> styles.css
```

If anyone has solutions for this it would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the styles.css in the following path:

> /android/app/src/main/assets

Then, set the baseURL of the `<WebView>` to the following:

```
<WebView source={{html: html, baseUrl: 'file:///android_asset/'}} />
```

P.S: You have to execute `react-native run-android` every time you made changes to the styling.

Comment: My code was almost working, except for the fact that the `href` in the `<link>` should of been prefixed by `/web`.

Comment: @NaotoIda I think the problem was because of the missing trailing `/` in your baseUrl, it should have been 'file:///android_asset/web/'. Once you fixed that, there is no need to prefix with '/web' in `href`.