# Add Local HTML and JS file using React Native Webview

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, highcharts

I want to load a local HTML file that imports a local javascript library using  tag in [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview).

I have tried many solutions but notihng worked on React native `0.60.5`.

- I have tried [this approach](https://medium.com/@snehabagri.90/reactnative-webview-with-local-content-c98a09340801), but I get Domain Not Found -1100 error on iOS.
- Tried [this](https://aboutreact.com/load-local-html-file-url-using-react-native-webview/) solution, but it did not work. (And the instructions were not clear for importing js file)

I am using :

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5"
```

PS: I am trying to implement [highcharts.js](https://www.highcharts.com) charting library in webView.

Comment: You can try to use also our official wrapper for react-native. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native

Comment: Thanks, @SebastianBochan I tried using the wrapper, but currently, there is this [issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native/issues/8) that is preventing me from using it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<View
        style={{
         flex:1
        }}
        >
          <WebView 
        scalesPageToFit
          originWhitelist={["*"]} 
          source={{ uri:"file:///android_asset/highcharts/index.htm",baseUrl:"file:///android_asset/highcharts/"

         }}/>

        </View>
```

Here is a working example of highchart in `react-native-webview`.

1. 1.First move all your `html/js` code to the following directory:
   `your_project/android/app/src/main/assets/`. If the `assets` folder does not exist already, create it.
2. Now paste all your `html/css/js` code in the `assets` folder you have created
3. close your terminal/cmd/bash or whatever you use to run `react-native run-android` command.
4. Run the following command now. `react-native run-android`.
5. Now paste the above code in your `.js` file. Set `uri` to the path to your html file such as `uri:"file:///android_asset/YOUR_HTML_FILE"` and your `baseUrl:"file:///android_asset/YOUR_MAIN_FOLDER/"`

   [image]

[image: Highcharts working in <code>react-native-webview</code>]

Comment: Hi @Ammar Thanks for answering. I wanted to import a local js file ( for offline support ). Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question. Can you please suggest me a way to import local js file within HTML? I have highcharts.js minified locally.

Comment: This might solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506908/react-native-webview-load-from-device-local-file-system

Comment: Check the 2nd answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not understand what that answer does. And those answers are like 3 years old.

Comment: I have made the changes. now it should work with local files

Comment: Thanks a lot. At first, I thought this is not working, because webView was not visible. But, later I realised you have to give a fixed height to Webview. `flex: 1` was not working for me.

Comment: Will you able to suggest me a way to suggest a similar approach for ios as well? Which folder should I put HTML and js?

Comment: I do not use react-native for ios development but it would be simple. you would have to place it in the same folder as you would place some images to load in your app. I have heard ios also has something like an assets folder but I am not sure.

Comment: Works for me as well. I'm also wondering about the ios asset folder