# swift UIWebView "freeze" animation in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

Need your help. I have UIWebView works with local content (html, css, javascript). All showing good. But, when user scroll content animations are "freezing". And continue working after scroll ended. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it UIWebView issue. Solution was to use WKWebView, not UIWebView. And working with it according this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28676439/4995378