# "@TRUE" in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

Recently I saw this code:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
[configuration.preferences setValue:@TRUE forKey:@"xxxx"];
```

What does `@TRUE` stands for? I'm seeing this construct for the first time.

I know that `YES` equals to `true` and

`@YES` equals to `NSNumber nubmerWithBool`, but what does the `@TRUE` stands for?

[StackOverflow question wtih example using "@TRUE" construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013645/setting-disable-web-security-and-allow-file-access-from-files-in-ios-wkwebvi)

Comment: By the way, in the answer you mention `@YES` would be a better solution.

Comment: Of course, it's the standard. The question was about the `@TRUE` as I've seen it for the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you preprocess:

```
NSNumber *test = @TRUE;
```

it ends up being

```
NSNumber *test = @1;
```

(a clang literal for `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]`).

which is logical, considering `TRUE` is preprocessed to `1`.

This might be easier to see on:

```
#define MY_STRING "my_string"

NSString *string = @MY_STRING;
```

which gets preprocessed to:

```
NSString *string = @"my_string";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an `NSNumber` literal, a way of creating `NSNumber` instances from scalar literal expressions.

From [The Clang 9 documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html):

> In Objective-C, any character, numeric or boolean literal prefixed
>   with the '@' character will evaluate to a pointer to an NSNumber
>   object initialized with that value. C’s type suffixes may be used to
>   control the size of numeric literals.