# WKWebView fails to load images and CSS using loadHTMLString(_, baseURL:)

Tags: ios, css, swift, image, wkwebview

[Apple's recommendation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview#overview):

> In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView.

Thus, I have replaced my good old `UIWebView` with a shiny new `WKWebView`. But what I thought to be an easy exercise (simply swapping the classes and replacing the delegate methods) turned out to be a real mess.

## The Problem

When I load an HTML string using

```
loadHTMLString(String, baseURL: URL?)
```

the web view loads and renders the pure HTML but **it doesn't load any images or CSS files referenced inside the `htmlString`**.

This happens **only on a real device**!
In Simultor all referenced resources are loaded correctly.

[image: Simulator]
[image: Real Device]

#### *Example*

I have defined a simple `htmlString` in my view controller class:

```
let imageName = "image.png"

let libraryURL: URL // The default Library URL

var htmlString: String {
    return "<html> ... <img src=\"\(imageName)\" /> ... </html>"
    // "..." represents more valid HTML code incl. header and body tags
}
```

The image is stored in the root Library folder so its URL is:

```
let imageURL = libraryURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
```

Now I load the `htmlString` into the web view:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: libraryURL)
```

and it doesn't load the image even though the `baseURL` is set correctly.

## Ideas for a Solution

1. Maybe `WKWebView` has a problem with resolving relative paths so my first idea was to use **absolute paths** inside the HTML string instead.
   → ❌ Doesn't work.
2. Two answers to [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882834/wkwebview-not-loading-local-files-under-ios-8) suggested that using
   `loadFileURL(URL, allowingReadAccessTo: URL)`
   instead of `loadHTMLString(...)` works in iOS 9+.
   → ✅ That works.

However, I cannot use solution 2 because my HTML files are encrypted and the decrypted files must not be stored on the disk.

## Question

Is there any way to load local resources like images and styles using the `WKWebView`'s

```
loadHTMLString(String, baseURL: URL?)
```

function? Or is still a bug in iOS 9+?

*(I just cannot believe that Apple provides and recommends using a web view that cannot load any local web content from inside an HTML string?!)*

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http

Comment: I am having the same issue. Tried with "loadFileURL(URL, allowingReadAccessTo: URL)". It is still not working for me. Images are still not loading for me. How did you get it to work?

Comment: How did you get it to work?

Comment: It is 3 years and 8 month later and yet I am still stuck with the very same issue

Comment: @Solomiya Well, WKWebView is quite a thing... ‍♂️

Comment: @Mischa so, did you succeed to finally solve this issue? I can see no answer was accepted. Could you share the approach that actually helped you?

Comment: Honestly, I don’t remember exactly. I think we found some workaround or used a different approach altogether. But I think I never really got an answer why this doesn’t work. Otherwise I would have answered my own question here...

Comment: @Solomiya  did u find any workable solution to that ?
Can you help me in a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800637/unable-to-load-html-with-only-images-in-wkwebview-ios-13-swift-5

Answer (score 16):

Without taking a look at your actual project it's difficult to give some hundreed percent sure advices.

However:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let views = [
            "webView" : webView
        ]
        view.addSubview(webView)
        var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[webView]|", options: [.AlignAllLeading, .AlignAllTrailing], metrics: nil, views: views)
        constraints.appendContentsOf(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[webView]|", options: [.AlignAllTop, .AlignAllBottom], metrics: nil, views: views))
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraints)

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ios - WKWebView fails to load images and CSS using loadHTMLString(_, baseURL_) - Stack Overflow", ofType: "htm")
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        webView.loadHTMLString(try! String(contentsOfURL: url), baseURL: url.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I think the key point here is `baseUrl` parameter, you should setup it correctly. In my case i've used html's url without last path component - e.g. containing folder. This works fine on both device & simulator - check device snapshot. I've uploaded sample project to  https://github.com/soxjke/WKWebViewTest so you can take a look (i've removed codesigning info from git)

[image: Device snapshot]

So, to recap - method is working, functionality is working, just you do something wrong with it. To help you get what's wrong with your solutions, i'll add some suggestions:
 1. Remember, that simulator filesystem is **case-insensitive**, device filesystem is **case-sensitive**. So if you have your filenames in html in lowercase - this won't work on device. `8fFsD.png != 8ffsd.png`
 2. Remember, that when copying resources, XCode ignores your folder structure. So if your html has `<img src="./img/1.png">` and your XCOde project has folder structure like

```
test.htm

img/

    1.png 
    2.png
```

After build it will be flattened, so test.htm and 1.png and 2.png will reside on same level

```
test.htm
1.png 
2.png
```

I'm almost sure, after you verify these two assumptions, you'll get this method working.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the sample project on GitHub. With that I've been able to make the webview load the resources on my iPhone. I haven't quite figured out what's wrong with my implementation and why it's working only in the Simulator but I'll look into it as soon as I get the time and will post my findings in another answer on this page.

Comment: Glad that my answer helps. As i've written, i suggest to check filenames and case first, and folder structure next. 99% you will find an issue.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please check my question where HTMLString is a requirement for me, facing same issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050435/images-from-document-directory-is-not-visible-in-webview-it-is-working-fine-for

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem today, I've found the solution and potentially the cause:

```
loadHTMLString(String, baseURL: URL?)
```

This function doesn't allow the rendered HTML to access local media, as far as I'm aware, this is because it would be an injection risk, this could allow rendered HTML to access and manipulate your local file system. With a html string, that could come from anywhere or anyone.

```
loadFileURL(URL, allowingReadAccessTo: URL)
```

With this function, you point the WKWebview to the html file in your FileManager, and to the containing folder with 'allowingReadAccessTo'. Because the html is stored within the FileManager, it will allow the rendered HTML to access locally stored media.

If you don't have the html file stored locally for some reason(I assume you do), You could write the html sting into a .html file, then point to the URL of that file. However, this is just subverting Apple's protection, so do it at your own peril (don't do it).

This is just the solution that worked for me and my understanding of why we're having the problem to begin with.

Edit #1: Typo.

Edit #2: I've since found another nuance, When stating the 'allowingReadAccessTo:' URL, if the HTML itself needs to access things in parent folders (ie: .css, .js files), you need to specify the parent folder, not necessarily the location of the HTML itself, this will then implicitly allow access to the child folders as required also. For me, this problem was only apparent on a physical device, this didn't seem to have an effect whilst running in simulator, likely another discrepancy between how permissions work on simulator and a physical device.

Comment: This was it! CSS stopped working after moving to WKWebView which worked perfectly fine in UIWebView. Now that I save html to a file and read it as file url with `allowingReadAccessTo:` to, everything loads fine.

Comment: @green0range if u could help me out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800637/unable-to-load-html-with-only-images-in-wkwebview-ios-13-swift-5

Answer (score 3):

Well you should be able to use local images and CSS files (and JavaScript files for that matter) with WKWebViews with the function that you have already found. My guess is that the problem is with your `baseURL` variable.

**Update 7.5.2017:**

I have completely updated the code from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336235/wkwebview-does-load-resources-from-local-document-folder/39459878#39459878) of mine that used to be linked to my answer here. I have a working project for `loadHTMLString()` and `.loadFileURL()`

Comment: Have you tried that on a real device? Because this is pretty much what I have done. The `baseURL` is supposed to be the location from which your relative paths are resolved but the issue can't really be related to that because I've tried referencing absolute paths in the HTML as well and it doesn't work either.

Comment: (Btw: Once you figure out the quirks *everything* is quite alright. There shouldn't be any quirks in the first place!)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I had to switch to using [XWebView](https://github.com/XWebView/XWebView) as the out-of-the-box behavior of WKWebView does not allow loading of local files.  XWebView tricks it by loading up a local web server in the background and directing local traffic thru it. (XWebView is based on top of WKWebView)

Seems a bit overkill, but that is what I ended up having to do.

Comment: Thanks for the adivce. I've read about this web server trick in other posts. But it really feels like a big overkill to use an external library to setup a local web server just to render some basic HTML - a task that's a webview's main purpose!

Answer (score 3):

I've been experimenting with this as well, with similar restrictions, and the problem appears to be that paths aren't resolved unless `baseURL` references the application bundle. It doesn't work if you, for example, have something in the application's documents.

Edit: I have filed a radar for this [rdar://29130863](https://openradar.appspot.com/29130863)

Comment: I have the exact same problem as the rdar. Any chance you remember what you end up doing? :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to create `baseURL` using:

`let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "#path#")`

instead of:

`let baseURL = URL(string: "#path#")`

The main difference is that the first method adds `file://` prefix before the path.

Answer (score 2):

You can base64 encode the images... I know that works.  Not sure if it will be appropriate for your use case though.

Kind of funny, I just ran into this problem while doing the opposite - moving from base64 encoded to image files.

Comment: Sounds like a smart work-around! Will try that. However, it really feels like dirty hacking in my case because I'll have to parse the HTML, find all image URLs, encode them as base64 data and replace the URL with the data.

Comment: yea, I can see that.  In my case I already have the image that i want to get into the html so it was a bit cleaner.

Comment: I've tried base64 encoding the images and it still does not work. https://github.com/starkindustries/Print2PDFTest

Answer (score 2):

When I used UIWebview, I used baseURL as,

```
let baseUrl = NSURL(string: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "cms", ofType: "html")!)! as URL

webView.loadHTMLString(bodyPage, baseURL: baseUrl)
```

But for the WKWebView, I used baseURL as

```
let baseUrl = Bundle.main.bundleURL

webView.loadHTMLString(bodyPage, baseURL: baseUrl)
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old already, but I ran into the exact same problem and it took me hours of trials and even to find this thread with the same problem (Xamarin Forms App)

My issue was: parsing remote HTML content into a string and also adding locally saved images (also downloaded dynamically, no resource of the app). On the simulator all works well, but on acutal device the local images are not showing (also no ? or anything indicating an error, just a blank frame). The Xamarin webview also offers the "BaseURL" option which didn't help, also not to use the BaseURL on the custom iOS wkWebView.

The only working solution as pointed out by Scott above, is to write the HTML into a file and then use the "LoadFileUrl" function and allow read access to the base directory. This also works with absolute file paths for images in the HTML (not only relative to the basedir, but of course somewhere within the basedir).

My custom webview renderer to load web and local content looks like this now:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    NSUrl baseURL = new NSUrl(App.dirNews, true);
    string viewFile = Path.Combine(App.dirNews, "view.html");
    NSUrl fileURL = new NSUrl(viewFile, false);

    switch (e.PropertyName) {
        case "Url":
            System.Console.WriteLine("--- Loading Web page ---");
            System.Console.WriteLine("--- " + Element.Url + " ---");
            NSUrlRequest myRequest = new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Url), NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, 120);
            Control.LoadRequest(myRequest);
            break;

        case "HTML":
            System.Console.WriteLine("--- Showing HTTP content ---");
            File.WriteAllText(viewFile, Element.HTML, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            Control.LoadFileUrl(fileURL, baseURL);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure this out, but based on this answer I got it working:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73519282/5868066

Try this:

```
let htmlPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "")
let htmlDirectory = htmlPath.deletingLastPathComponent() 
let htmlString = try! String(contentsOfFile: htmlPath.path, encoding: .utf8) 

let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlDirectory)
let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[.zero]

webView.loadFileURL(htmlPath, allowingReadAccessTo: documentsDirectory)
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: baseURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce a similar issue. WKWebView loads my images specially if they are located remotely, apart from my app server.

For servers that are not SSL-secured (http instead of https), you can set your `info.plist` as per below:

```
App Transport Security Settings

 - Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content (Set to YES)
 - Allow Arbitrary Loads (Set to YES)
```

The problem was actually in the server. The server application was either:

- Changing the image src from `"http://IP-or-domain/uploads/file.jpg"` to `"../../uploads/file.jpg"`

***- OR -***

- The image src was `"http://localhost/uploads/file.jpg"` **or** `"http://127.0.0.1/uploads/file.jpg"` **instead of** `"http://YOUR-SERVER-IP-ADDRESS/uploads/file.jpg"`

In these cases, the actual device wont be able to locate the image. This only works with iOS Simulator because the virtual device is the same as the server and development machine. It can read `LOCALHOST` and `127.0.0.1`.

In my server, I was using a Rich Text Editor (TinyMCE) and it automatically removes the IP address after it detects that it's the same source.

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView can load image or css file from NSTemporaryDirectory, so you can copy your files to NSTemporaryDirectory, and then load it. It works for me on iOS 14!  see this issue. [ios-wkwebview-loadhtmlstring-baseurl-fails-to-load-images-and-read-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60025501/ios-wkwebview-loadhtmlstring-baseurl-fails-to-load-images-and-read-css)