# Load Images from https URL within HTML on WebView

Tags: html, ios, swift, image, uiwebview

I am trying to load an HTML file on WebView. The HTML contains image URLs. When I try to run that image URL on Web Browser, it works. The image gets displayed. But the same image does not get loaded in WebView in my app.

I found this [question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18321) on Apple Developer Forum, it is still unanswered. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar issue a few months ago, and I fixed it by replacing `UIWebView` with `WKWebView`.

`WKWebView` is the official replacement of `UIWebView`, take a look at [its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview):

> Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content
>   to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.

Comment: Hello, I am facing same issue with WKWebView also. Actually, the HTML I am using is the Page Source of some random webPage. If this can be the issue for images not getting displayed ?

Comment: The images that I stored locally in XCode are displayed in WebView. The issue is with images that are needed to fetch from URL in HTML.

Comment: This is weird. Using `WKWebView` was enough for me. Take a look at the discussion here, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901982/wkwebview-fails-to-load-images-and-css-using-loadhtmlstring-baseurl

Comment: In my case i tried first using webview but not loaded images it shows boxes instead of images. then i tried wkwebview it also not shown images.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to fetch your images using WKWebView.

Step 1: import WebKit in your class

```
import WebKit
```

Step 2: Add WebKit delegate to your controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate
```

Step 3: create variable of `WKWebView` type

```
var webView: WKWebView!
```

Step 4: Configure WKWebView. Override `loadView()` function with following line of code

```
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
```

Step 5: In `viewDidLoad()` pass `URLRequest` to `webView()`

```
let url = "your URL"
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
webView.load(request)
```