# Inject CSS into WKWebview using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, swift, wkwebview

I am using a WKWebview to display HTML. I would like to style the HTML using a locally hosted CSS file. I have tried many of the proposed solutions from the following posts, but have not been able to make them work for me.

- [Insert CSS into loaded HTML in UIWebView / WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123093/insert-css-into-loaded-html-in-uiwebview-wkwebview)
- [WKWebView fails to load images and CSS using loadHTMLString(_, baseURL:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901982/wkwebview-fails-to-load-images-and-css-using-loadhtmlstring-baseurl?rq=1)
- [iOS WKWebview loadHTMLString(_ baseURL:) fails to load images and read css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60025501/ios-wkwebview-loadhtmlstring-baseurl-fails-to-load-images-and-read-css)

While I am able to manually hardcode `<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"markup.css\">` into the HTML and apply the CSS styles, I would love to know how to do this programmatically using JS or some other technique.

I created a [sample project](https://github.com/mattli/jsExample) to help illustrate the issue. I have commented out the hardcoded line that works, but am hoping someone can shed light onto why [this proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53141055/15027028) isn't working for me. Open to other suggestions as well. Thanks in advance!