# Swift3 : How to load html file to WKWebview from document directory

Tags: swift, wkwebview

Can anyone explain how to load local html file to WKWebView?

I tried with the below code works well in simulator but not on device

```
 let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
 let documentDirectoryPath: String = path[0]
 let fileManager = FileManager()

 let destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath + "/" + "\(NameF.fileName)/\(NameF.Languages)/page_\(i + 1 ).html")
 print("D2\(destinationURLForFile)")
 let request = NSURLRequest(url: destinationURLForFile)
 webView!.load(request as URLRequest)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: What `fileManager` is for? What's `NameF`?

Comment: Any error on device?

Comment: look to this answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/26202983/5251783

Comment: @Neha No errors thrown in console

Comment: @Honsy Thank you but this is to load file from project navigator. Am looking for files to load from local storage(document directory)

Comment: @Astoria NameF is nothing but the name of the folder inside document directory

Comment: did you try to laoding the HTML from 
        webview.loadHTMLString(string: String, baseURL: URL)

Comment: @Neha no i will try it and see.Can you give some example?

Comment: you can try this

  var webview: UIWebView!
    
    func loadFileFromLocal(){
        let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "privacy", ofType: "html")
        let content = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        let baseUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: htmlFile!)
        webview.loadHTMLString(content as String, baseURL: baseUrl as URL)
    }

Comment: @Neha thank you but the problem for me is i am using WKWebview not UIWebView

Comment: oh, sorry

Check with this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336235/wkwebview-does-load-resources-from-local-document-folder

Comment: @Neha even i tried that getting error

Comment: @Neha,@Honsy,@Astoria Thanks for your response guys finally found the answer

Comment: oh that's great!! how you solve it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response guys and for who tried my question.Finally found the answer by opening the local file and read its content and then send that string into a WKWebview

And the piece of code is

```
 do{
            let fileName =  try String(contentsOf: destinationURLForFile)
            print("fileName is equal to\(fileName)")
            webView.loadHTMLString(fileName, baseURL: destinationURLForFile)


        }catch{

        }
```