# uiwebview vs wkwebview, one can load the content and one cant

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

Currently, I'm using `WKWebView` to do `loadHTMLString(_ string: String, baseURL: URL?)` and for some reasons, it wont load the content page from the source. However, If I switch to `UIWebView` and do the same thing and surprisedly, content page can be displayed successfully. Below are my codes:

This is WKWebView:

```
 if let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: page.href, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    wkWebview.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: URL(string:book.resourceDir! + "/"))
 }
```

This is UIWebView:

```
 if let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: page.href, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
   webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: URL(string:book.resourceDir! + "/"))
}
```

Notice: the `html` and `baseURL`are identical for both `uiwebview` and `wkwebview`.

Have anyone had this problem and have any ideas about it. All comments are welcomed.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39459878/2529869, i hope it will solve your problem!

Comment: @NosovPavel: thanks for sharing this link.

Answer (score 0):

I want to provide you my solution:

```
wkWebview.loadHTMLString("<html><body>\(put_here)</body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

Just paste your variable that contains html code instead "**put_here**". If you string contains html tags like "html", "body" then remove them from **loadHTMLString()**