# Swift4 app crashes when loading local HTML

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

While working on a web app for weeks, I used a external URL in my (WKWebView) web view. Now I'm moving towards production I want to embed the webapp and load a local webpage.

I simply moved from

```
let url = URL(string: "http://hidden-url.com/")
self.webView!.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

To

```
let url = URL(string: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index_prod", ofType: "html")!)
self.webView!.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

But this causes my app to crash. I'm sure the file is loaded correctly and a `print` before, in-between and after the lines will appear in the console.

The error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)`

Comment: check whether you added index_prod file  into the target

Comment: I double checked it, it's listed in my project hierarchy and at 'Copy Bundle Resources' in the Build Phases

Comment: surround with try catch to get exception

Comment: Loading the file does not catch any exceptions, loading it into the web view will.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882834/wkwebview-not-loading-local-files-under-ios-8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336235/wkwebview-does-load-resources-from-local-document-folder You either have to use `loadHTMLString()` or `loadFileURL(url:allowingReadAccessTo:)`.

Comment: @Larme true, but that question is about Objective-C mine is about Swift.

Comment: @JeffreyLanters Both of my linked question have Swift code. Both explain WHY your code doesn't work and why you need to use a different approach. They may not be Swift 4 compliant, but the explanation in itself should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the string content from the file, use contentsOfFile method to get the string and use loadHTMLString method of webview, print the error or create some enum which shows the error

```
enum WebError: Swift.Error {
    case fileNotFound(name: String)
    case parsing(contentsOfFile: String)
}

guard let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index_prod", ofType: "html") else {
   throw WebError.fileNotFound(name: file) // throw file not found error 
}

do {
      let html = try String(contentsOfFile: url)
      self.webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
} catch {
      throw WebError.parsingError(contentsOfFile: file) 
}
```