# How to load html code in webview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am using  `mywebview.loadHTMLString(htmlCode, baseURL: nil)` but it's not working properly, means it doesn't support javascript and css, it only displayed the text inside that html code.

I am getting the html code from api and store it into the String data type and need to pass to the webview.

I have found one more thing `webview.load()` but it shows me "cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data'.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

This is my simple demo html code, which i wanted to display.But i am getting the color which i have used in above html.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a demo html code, <span style="background-color:#FF0000;">which i wanted to display on UIwebview</span> .</p>

<p>But <span style="color:#800080;">it&#39;s wokring</span> properly if i save this code as a<span style="color:#0000FF;"> .html</span> extension then works perfect.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share the html string?

Comment: Can you add your htmlcode that you are getting from api in question?

Comment: I have added demo html code. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't provide baseUrl as nil, Provide the URL where js, css and other files are located.

Comment: He mentioned getting the `htmlString` from the API. It should be fine to provide `baseURL` nil.

Comment: Even if html string is getting generated at server, the js and css dependencies must be present somewhere (may be on the same server), so UIWebView will need that path as baseURL to refer to those files.

Comment: I have added the sample html code in my post. please check it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415011-load) webview.load() expects data not a string. You can convert your html string to data:

```
guard let data = yourString.data(using: .utf8) else {
    print("Couldn't convert string to data")
    return
}
```

webview.loadHTMLString() should load html as a string. Your base url property is probably causing the issue. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336235/wkwebview-does-load-resources-from-local-document-folder/39459878#39459878) it's a working example of webview.loadHTMLString().

Comment: I have added the sample html code in my post. please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it's working for you

```
let webView = UIWebView()
webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

(OR)

```
let webView = UIWebView()
webView.loadHTMLString("\(htmlcode)", baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: I have added the sample html code in my post. Please check it.

Comment: not works in my case. i see all data but not in proper format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not escape all characters correctly. Please post the full code of what you tried. For example, if you put the following tag in a string:

```
<span style="background-color:#FF0000;">
```

You need to do it like

```
let span = "<span style=\"background-color:#FF0000;\">"
```

You can then put together your HTML string like this:

```
let html = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
        "<html>" +
        "<head>" +
        "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">"
```

and so on. To load the HTML string just use

```
webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```