# Why can not I display the local html file with MKWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, objective-c, xcode

I am creating an iOS application with Objective-C.

In summary, iTunes moved html, css, javascript files to iPad with folders.

Previously it was displayed in UIWebView, but I made it to WKWebView again.
Then, a problem has occurred!

Only css and javascript written outside of html are not loaded.
The css and javascript code written in html are executed.

Reading was done as follows.

`func loadFileURL(URL, allowingReadAccessTo: URL)`

Since all the external files are local, ATS has no problem.

Also, it can display correctly on the simulator. The problem occurs only in the iPad terminal at hand.

The environment I used is below.
· MacOS High Sierra 10.13.4
· Xcode 9.3 (9E145)
· IPad Air (iOS 11.2.6)

People who understand the solution, seeking those who are cognizant of the cause!

Comment: You can find something in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33126467/2776008

Comment: I do not seem to be able to solve it. I found one new thing. `<a>` tag link also does not work. Is this also due to WK Webbiew security settings?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336235/wkwebview-does-load-resources-from-local-document-folder I think this will helps you to load your local HTM assets.

Comment: Share your code please.