# WKWebView does not load local html files

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` that works perfectly fine when given a `URL` or a `URLRequest`, but when I am trying to load local bundle html files into it, it just doesn't display anything.

I am trying it like so:

```
let webView = WKWebView()

if let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "mySubDirectory/v1") {
    webView.loadFileURL(bundleURL, allowingReadAccessTo: bundleURL.deletingLastPathComponent())
}
```

I have tested that the `bundleURL` actually returns the right path and tried copying + pasting it in my browser at run time and it works great:
`file:///Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FireApp-gugmufgdkejtfdhglixebzhokhfe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SteppingIntoFireFramwork.framework/mySubDirectory/v1/index.html`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the URL works, then it seems that your webview is having trouble loading it.

I once had this issue... Check that you don’t have only “http” & “https” enabled for the allowed URL scheme

Comment: OMFG, someone actually enabled `http` and `https` only for the webview to load! Thanks a lot! I would not have found it otherwise :O

Comment: Where is that option? I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Gerard I can not find it either.  It used to be under `Info.pList`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let webView = WKWebView()
        let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
        let htmlUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!, isDirectory: false)
        webView.loadFileURL(htmlUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: htmlUrl)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

[Full solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39459878/948445)

Answer (score 0):

Your web view is just a local temporary variable. It has zero size and is not in the interface, so you never see anything happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove deletingLastPathComponent() from your example.
Also you can try to use load(request) instead of loadFileURL().

```
if let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "mySubDirectory/v1") {
    let request = URLRequest(url: bundleURL)
    webView.load(request)
}
```