# How to load javascript and css resources from Document directory of iPad using WKWebview?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift3, wkwebview

I have added all .js, .css and .html files in Device document directory. On simulator , WKWebview is able to load HTML with all resources successfully but on device it is not able to load .js and .css files.

I am using this code -

```
let baseURL = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/61AAA238-BE0C-4CD1-8401-58D0A40BBDF0/Documents/SitePlanResources/"
do {
   let fullPath = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/61AAA238-BE0C-4CD1-8401-58D0A40BBDF0/Documents/SitePlanResources/sitemap_708_193.html"
   let htmlString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: fullPath!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
   _ = self.masterWebView?.loadHTMLString(htmlString as String, baseURL: baseURL)
   } catch {
       print(error)
   }
```

In HTML, I am referencing HTML like -

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=6.0" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="preview.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="simple-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="jquery.svg.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="MasterSitePlan.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="Tap.js"></script>
    <script  src="fastclick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="simple-slider.js"></script>
    <style>
        svg {
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

All files are stored in same location. 
I got stuck in this problem. Need some help.

Comment: how you are referencing HTML and JS in html. is this HTML working in browser correctly .when opening the file alone.

Comment: yes, its working correctly in browser. I have edited the question . Please check again.

Comment: Have a look at below answer its a limitation of WKWebview . You can use UIWebview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882834/wkwebview-not-loading-local-files-under-ios-8) of WKWebView to not be able to load a local file, you can load a simple content with `loadHTMLString`, but this will not set a base path from which the related files will be loaded even if possible.

If you don't need to support <=ios8 then you can use a new API for such purpose `[WKWebView loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:]`

Otherwise you will probably have to either embed the needed css/js in the html or use the standard UIWebView or Safari view or another private browser view.