# Why Angular 8 router is not working in Cordova IOS with WkWebView?

Tags: angular, cordova, wkwebview, angular-router, cordova-ios

I have an existing application built with `Angular` 8 and its code is shared by a website and 2 mobile applications for `Android` and `IOS`, bundled with the help of `Cordova`.
It is working fine but Apple has announced that they will soon no longer supports apps built with `UIWebView`:

> The App Store will no longer accept new apps using UIWebView as of April 2020 and app updates using UIWebView as of December 2020.

So I am forced to migrate it to `WkWebView`. There are several threads that I am aware of in the `Cordova` repository and elsewhere, that talk about possible migration plans (see [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/661) for example).
I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538510/angular-2-0-router-navigation-not-working-on-ios-wkwebview) other question but it is old (different version of Angular) and doesn't provide any concrete solution.

So I decided to go with the [cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) plugin which seemed to be the simplest solution in my case.
Everything went well until I launched my app in the IOS simulator and see that routing is no longer working.
I managed reducing the issue to the minimal possible Angular app with routing, which you can see working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-routing-for-cordova-issue).
I put all the steps needed to reproduce the issue in this [repository](https://github.com/sasensi/cordova-ios-angular).

The following steps require having `node`, `npm` and `cordova` installed globally:
 1. clone repository: `git clone https://github.com/sasensi/cordova-ios-angular.git`
 2. move to repository directory: `cd cordova-ios-angular`
 3. install dependencies: `npm i`
 4. create cordova project: `cordova create cordova com.demo.app DemoApp`
 5. build Angular app: `npm run build`
 6. move to cordova directory: `cd cordova`
 7. add WkWebView plugin: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`
 8. add `<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true"/>` in `./config.xml`
 9. add cordova IOS platform: `cordova platform add ios`
10. open `platforms/ios/DemoApp.xcodeproj` in XCode (10.1)
11. run with `IPhone X` simulator
12. See that routing doesn't work: nothing is rendered below the navigation section (whereas there should be the current page content)

As mentioned in the repository, everything is working as expected when using `UIWebView` (skipping steps `7.` and `8.`)

I hope that someone already faced the same issue and can help me make my existing Angular application work in this new context.

Comment: With Cordova iOS 6 you no longer need the wkwebview plugin but I still had the same issue. Your location strategy stuff was a huge help, thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After digging deeper, the issue was linked to the fact that in `WkWebView`, files are loaded with the `file://` protocol and this protocol is not compatible with `Angular` [LocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/LocationStrategy).
I found a workaround [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13948#issuecomment-273833138), which consist in using [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy) instead and setting `<base>` element `href` attribute value to `document.location`.
In or to do that, you have to replace the common `<base>` element by `<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>` which creates it at runtime.

Comment: Thanks alot! With Angular 9 + Cordova

Comment: Any idea when I am running into `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` issues when it is trying to load the compiled .js files?

Comment: @CularBytes try opening your chrome browser with this command inside the run application(win + R): chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session/test" --disable-web-security

Comment: Winner Winner Chicken Dinner. Solved my NG11 + Cordova problem.

Answer (score 0):

When using `HashLocationStrategy` for iOS the app finally started working - thanks for finding that out.

However, I want to mention that it is not neccessery to add

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

because `HashLocationStrategy` does not need `<base>` flag. It works without it. Just make sure it is not in index.html if you build for iOS