# Router issue with Angular and Cordova for specific to iOS platform

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, router, hybrid-mobile-app

I have built an application, but I have some issue with this.router.navigate I have wrap an Angular 9 with Apache Cordova and build successfully installed on device but when I clicked on login button to navigate on dashboard I got some issue and didn't navigate.
But if I remove cordova.js from index.html router.navigate working fine. All this working fine on Android platform but not on iOS. If somebody have some suggestion to fix it, I appreciate.

Comment: Hello Avinash,
Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866439/why-angular-8-router-is-not-working-in-cordova-ios-with-wkwebview

Comment: Hi Jaimin, As suggested by given url I did changed in my index.html but still facing same issue, app didn't route. But once I remove cordova.js app working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
<base href="." />
```