# UniWebView playing audio from local storage

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, audio, wkwebview, uniwebview

Using UniWebView we try to display a locally stored html page to play audio that is stored in a sub-folder at the same location as the page. While this works fine for iOS 10, 11; we seem to have a problem on iOS 9 where the audio doesn't play. After inspecting the page in Safari, there was an error when fetching the resource from local storage but it did not say why. Implementation for playing audio is the same for all iOS versions.

Wanted to ask if there are any limitations to iOS 9 or specific rules of how to fetch and play audio files the from local storage?

PS.: UniWebView is a wrapper for WkWebView on iOS

[Error screenshot from Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFm1q.png)

Comment: how are the local files referenced in the html? can you show some code please?

Comment: Added a screenshot that shows url used to access the file and the error thrown. We did not see anything useful in xcode logs.

Comment: please try on iOS9 without "file.//" in the file name when referencing it in the html

Comment: I mean `file://`

Comment: how do you load your webpage? do you do it like this `[WKWebView loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:]`?

Comment: The link for the audio is as follows: 
`<audio preload="false" volume="1.0" type="audio/mpeg" src="/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4B58F8B5-5CE3-4CE9-9E20-A4121F2F5AEB/Documents/assets/audio/no_en-GB_9460bdf8662ec349e45757d6b936f833-ca3e2a2e3937c297e60ac36842a4ee58.mp3"></audio>`

So we are not directly specifying `file://`
As for second question, we are using a third party wrapper so we don't know. But we can contact the developer of it.

Comment: so then can you please try adding `file://` if it maybe solves the problem for iOS 9?

Comment: Tried it, the same result. `src` shows `file://` added but the location that is shown in the Safari web inspector is the same as before

Comment: have you tried this method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414973-loadfileurl and pass in the local url of the folder where all your local files are located?

Comment: and can you please share the code where you load the website?

Comment: We are using a third party wrapper for WkWebView, so we are not calling any methods that are native to WkWebView and we do not have access to the source. The code for loading the website is written with the wrapper API so I don't see how that could help, but the function that we are using is documented here: http://docs.uniwebview.com/#/latest/api/uniwebview.html?id=load

Comment: does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/28676439/1113632 ?

Comment: I'll have to get the source access to UniWebView and see about it. I'll get back after that, thanks for help btw

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: We used a workaround - relying on browser cache to store preloaded  audio files. WebView has no problem playing those.